# ExtJS 3 grid columnresize or tools handler

Tags: javascript, extjs, event-handling, extjs3, gridpanel

I am working with ExtJS 3.4, I want to add `tools` on grid when one of the grid's column moved or resized. And after that I want to add a handler to this dynamically created tools. If this is not possible, I want to handle `tools` handler dynamically on `columnresize`.

My code is like below:

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    title       : _title,
    autoHeight  : true,
    collapsible : true,
    colModel    : _myColModel,
    store       : _myStore,
    tools:[{
        type        :   'plus',
        hidden      :   false,
        handler     :   function(event, toolEl, panel){
            // do something
        }
    }]
});

grid.on('columnresize', function(argColIndex, argNewWidth){
    // do something
});
```